# How do I remove an entire call tree from pycallgraph with a filter

Tags: python-3.x, pycallgraph

I want to see what's happening with a specific operation in a python3 package I've been working on. I use pycallgraph and it looks great. But I can't figure out how to remove an entire tree of calls from the output.

I made a quick script `make_call_graphs.py`:

```
import doms.client.schedule as sched
from pycallgraph import PyCallGraph
from pycallgraph.output import GraphvizOutput
from pycallgraph import Config
from pycallgraph import GlobbingFilter

config = Config()
config.trace_filter = GlobbingFilter(exclude=[
    '_find_and_load',
    '_find_and_load.*', # Tried a few similar variations
    '_handle_fromlist',
    '_handle_fromlist.*',
])

with PyCallGraph(output=GraphvizOutput(output_file='schedule_hourly_call_graph.png'), config=config):
    sched.hourly()
```

Before I started using the `GlobbingFilter`, `_find_and_load` was at the top of the tree outside of my `doms` library call stack. It seems that the filter only removes the top level block, but every subsequent call remains in the output. (See BEFORE and AFTER below)

Obviously I can read the result and copy every single call I don't want to see into the filter, but that is silly. What can I do to remove that whole chunk of stuff outside my `doms` box? Is there a `RecursiveFilter` or something I could use?

BEFORE:
[image]
AFTER:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was much easier than I originally thought and right in front of me: the `include` kwarg given to the `GlobbingFilter`.

```
config.trace_filter = GlobbingFilter(include=['__main__', 'doms.*'])
```